# Windowsアプリ（C++）でTIFF画像の表示をしたい。

Tags: c++, windows

お世話になっております。

Windowsアプリ（C++）にてTIFF画像を表示したいと思っているのですが、
「Windows Imaging Component」を利用することで、
TIFF画像データの読み込み＆編集＆保存ができることはわかったのですが、
表示（描画）方法がわかりません。

HDCを使って表示したいのですが、そのようなAPIが
見つかりませんでした。

「Windows Imaging Component」にこだわりはありませんので、
TIFF画像の表示方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

開発環境
OS: Windows10
IDE: VS2019
言語: C++

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こんなプロジェクトがあります。[Image Viewer Utility](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1655/Image-Viewer-Utility), [Multipage TIF Viewer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31247/Multipage-TIF-Viewer), [VC++ / C++ Source Code ATL Links -- Image Editor!](http://www.ucancode.net/VC_Source_Code.htm)

Comment: いっぱいあるんですね。C++もパッケージシステムが使えたら嬉しいんですけどね・・・。

Comment: 今ではパッケージシステムありますよ。充実しているかどうかは判りませんが。[vcpkg: Windows、Linux、および MacOS 用の C++ パッケージ マネージャー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019)

Comment: あったんですね！
知りませんでした。
ご教授、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

クラスCImageが使えると思います。

```
CImage::Load( ファイル名); //ファイルから読み込み
CImage::Draw( HDC,・・・); // HDCに描画
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
CImageで上手く行きました！