# Windowsアプリ（C++）でPDFの表示をしたい

Tags: windows, pdf

Windowsアプリ（C++）にてPDFを表示したいと思っているのですが、おすすめのライブラリとかありますでしょうか。

開発環境
OS: Windows10
IDE: VS2019
言語: C++

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺からどれか、他にも色々ありそうですが。[PDFソフトウェアの一覧](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7), [TeX Wiki PDF](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?PDF), [PDF](http://pdf-file.nnn2.com/)

Comment: Windows-10タグがつけられていますが、実行環境がWindows 10固定なのでしょうか？ 開発環境をタグ付けしても無意味だと思います。

Comment: どのライセンスをお探しですか？ 無料で無料のオープンソースライブラリのみをお探しですか？ それとも、有料の商用SDKを受け入れますか？ どのフレームワークを使用していますか？

Answer (score 0):

使えるかどうかわかりませんが、下記のようなライブラリがあるようです。
http://libharu.sourceforge.net/
http://podofo.sourceforge.net/
http://www.jagpdf.org/
また、AdobeからもSDKが出ています。

Comment: これらのライブラリはどれもPDFファイルを実際にレンダリングできません。

Answer (score 0):

実行環境がWindows 8.1以降であれば、[`IPdfRendererNative`インターフェース](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.data.pdf.interop/nn-windows-data-pdf-interop-ipdfrenderernative)を使用して描画できます。
Egtraさんのサンプル、[Direct2DでPDFを描画するAPIを使ってみた](https://dev.activebasic.com/egtra/2015/12/24/853/)も参考にしてください。
この場合、前質問の[Windowsアプリ（C++）でTIFF画像の表示をしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60718/4236)もDirect2Dを使うことで処理を共通化できるかもしれません。